# Thread-safety while using @Async annotation

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous, thread-safety

I am using the java `@async` annotation in my **spring-boot** application for processing and uploading excel files. It is working fine even if I am doing a multiple file upload at roughly the same time. However, I want to know if the below code that I have implemented is thread-safe or not. My understanding is that it is not and it can fail. I am unable to reproduce the concurrency issue

My Code:

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {  
    Row row=rowIterator.next();

    if(row.getRowNum()==0) 
        continue;

    BatchScript script=new BatchScript();                       
    String rtId=row.getCell(0).toString();
    String query=row.getCell(1).toString();
    String agent=row.getCell(2).toString();
    script.setRtId(rtId);
    script.setQuery(query);
    script.setAgentName(agent);
}
```

In the code BatchScript is my POJO class. Can you please let me know if it will fail or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Rows collection is shared by multiple threads, then there is a possibility of `ConcurrentModificationException`. This will be the case when threads mutating your Rows list. If not there is no shared mutability in your code and so we can say that it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object you are creating is in a method call, it is a local object and all local objects are thread-safe.